# rowMeans with all columns that share a string

Tags: r, string

I have a big df like this (this is just part of it). For each sample (A, B, C. etc, I have hundred of them) I have 3 values (R, H, and L).

```
IDs R.A R.B R.C H.A H.B H.C L.A L.B L.C
A   6   5   4   5   5   5   5   1   4
B   2   5   3   3   4   3   5   5   6
C   6   6   3   2   2   1   4   1   3
D   2   1   6   3   5   3   3   6   5
E   4   1   3   2   3   1   4   4   4
F   3   1   1   1   4   4   2   6   4
```

I want create a new df with the `rowMeans` for each sample, in this example:

```
   IDs  mean.A  mean.B  mean.C
    A   3.0 5.0 3.0
    B   5.7 5.3 4.7
    C   3.0 4.7 4.7
    D   3.0 1.7 5.3
    E   3.3 4.0 4.3
    F   4.0 2.3 4.0
```

I know how to do it for this example, but I have hundred of them, and I can't do it specifying the string manually (A, B, C).

```
newcols <- sapply(c("A$", "B$", "C$"), function(x) rowMeans(df[grep(x, names(df))]))
setNames(cbind(df[1], newcols), c(names(df)[1], "mean.A", "mean.B", "mean.C"))
```

Is there any way to do an operation with all columns that share a "string" without specifying the "string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a constant pattern `R.` `H.` or `L.` followed by the strings of interest, use the pattern to extract all the unique samples you need to look through:

```
findThese <- unique(sub(pattern = "^[RHL]\\.(.+)$",
                        replacement = "\\1",
                        x = colnames(df)[!names(df) == "IDs"], # don't grab IDs column
                        perl = TRUE))
```

Then use the unique samples you found (`findThese`) in your code:

```
newcols <- sapply(paste0(findThese, "$"), function(x) rowMeans(df[grep(x, names(df))]))
setNames(cbind(df[1], newcols), c(names(df)[1], paste0("mean", findThese)))
#  IDs   mean.A   mean.B   mean.C
#1   A 5.333333 3.666667 4.333333
#2   B 3.333333 4.666667 4.000000
#3   C 4.000000 3.000000 2.333333
#4   D 2.666667 4.000000 4.666667
#5   E 3.333333 2.666667 2.666667
#6   F 2.000000 3.666667 3.000000
```

Answer (score 5):

Rename so that you have `Group.[RHL]`, melt to long format, then `aggregate`:

```
names(dat) <- sub("^(.+)\\.(.+)$", "\\2.\\1", names(dat))
long <- reshape(dat, idvar="IDs", direction="long", sep=".", varying=-1, timevar=NULL)
aggregate(. ~ IDs, data=long, FUN=mean)

#  IDs        A        B        C
#1   A 5.333333 3.666667 4.333333
#2   B 3.333333 4.666667 4.000000
#3   C 4.000000 3.000000 2.333333
#4   D 2.666667 4.000000 4.666667
#5   E 3.333333 2.666667 2.666667
#6   F 2.000000 3.666667 3.000000
```

Shouldn't be hard to adapt a similar logic to `dplyr` or `data.table` - but I'll leave that for someone else today.

Comment: @akrun - not at all - I see it's quite clean in data.table

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table` to `melt` the dataset into 'long' format as it takes multiple `measure` `patterns` and then get the `mean` by 'IDs'.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("A$", "B$", "C$"), 
   value.name = c("A", "B", "C"))[,lapply(.SD, mean) , IDs, .SDcols = A:C]
#   IDs        A        B        C
#1:   A 5.333333 3.666667 4.333333
#2:   B 3.333333 4.666667 4.000000
#3:   C 4.000000 3.000000 2.333333
#4:   D 2.666667 4.000000 4.666667
#5:   E 3.333333 2.666667 2.666667
#6:   F 2.000000 3.666667 3.000000
```